# Django View with two Slugs

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, django-2.0

How to write a Django View with two slugs?

**Each slug is from different Models.**

I want to get www.example.com/category/slug1/slug2

Please provide an example code.

Views.py

```
class SubjectDetailView(generic.DetailView, SingleObjectMixin):
    model           = Programmesearch
    template_name   = 'mnsdirectory/subject_detail.html'
    slug_field      = 'subjectslug'
    slug_url_kwarg  = 'subjectslug'
```

Urls.py

```
app_name    = 'mnsdirectory'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'), #views.indexSubjectDetailView(View)
    path('study/<slug:subjectslug>/', views.SubjectDetailView.as_view(), name='subject-detail'),
    path('study-abroad/<slug:studylevelslug>/', views.StudylevelDetailView.as_view(), name='studylevel-list'),
    ]
```

Models.py:

```
class Programmesearch(models.Model):
    full_subject_name   =   models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    subjectslug         =   models.SlugField(unique=True, editable=False, max_length=100)

class StudyLevel(models.Model):
    study_level     = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    studylevelslug  = models.SlugField(unique=True, editable=False, max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

good first that my advice personally is that you have to have a good base of POO PYTHON and know well the MVT architecture, Django works a very similar architecture the MVC model view controller, now in View it goes all the logical part of python and there is where we will declare or whether we are going to end in which Template we are going to paint data processed by VIEW-Server.

Well, first of all how you want to work with those 2 models what we will do is the following:

We import the following methods

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View

class SubjectDetailView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Programmesearch.objects.all()        
        return render(request, 'mnsdirectory/subject_detail.html', {'element':queryset})
```

finally simply in the url you place this:

```
path('study/slug1/slug2/', views.SubjectDetailView.as_view(), name='subject-detail'),
```

Comment: Dear @jpozzo, thank you for your solution. But, slugs are from different models.

Answer (score 1):

perfect then send to the temple a dictionary a little more complex with 2 keys:

```
class SubjectDetailView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Programmesearch.objects.all()
        queryset2 = StudyLevel.objects.all()           
        return render(request, 'mnsdirectory/subject_detail.html', {'element':queryset,'element2':queryset2})
```

Comment: **Dear @jpozzo, thank you very much for your help. It worked but now, I get a NoReverseMatch error when I have a Programmesearch file in the database.**

**Error:**
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'subject-detail' with arguments '('corporate-finance', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['study/(?P<studylevelslug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<subjectslug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

**Link in HTML:**
<a href="{% url 'mnsdirectory:subject-detail' programmesearch.subjectslug studylevel.studylevelslug %}">hello</a>

Answer (score 0):

@ulvi-damirli. You can use your **urls.py** like this:

Urls.py

```
re_path(r'^(?P<slug>[\w_-]+)/(?P<studylevel>[\w_-]+)/$', 
            views.SubjectDetailView.as_view(), name='subject-detail'),
```

and in your **views.py**, you can catch these slugs like this:

Views.py

```
class SubjectDetailView(generic.DetailView, SingleObjectMixin):
    model           = Programmesearch
    template_name   = 'mnsdirectory/subject_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # subjectslug = self.object.slug # Not necessary since It's a DetailView
        studyLevel = StudyLevel.objects.filter(
                            study_level=self.kwargs.get('studylevel', None))
```

Hope I helped you, let me know if It worked